# How should I calculate the Time complexity for the below code?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, in-place

The below solution is to calculate the in-place frequency count of the numbers present in the array

```
int arr[] = {4, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 1, 2, 5};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

cout << "size: " << size << "\n";

for(int i = 0; i < size;) {
    if(arr[i] > size) {
        arr[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    if(arr[i] <= 0) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    int indexToUpdate = arr[i] - 1;
    if(arr[indexToUpdate] < 0) {
        arr[i] = 0;
        arr[indexToUpdate]--;
        i++;
    } else {
        arr[i] = arr[indexToUpdate];
        arr[indexToUpdate] = -1;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << i << " : " << arr[i] << "\n";
}
```

the time complexity for the solution.

Comment: Looks O(n) to me. Do you have any reason to believe that this is not the case?

Comment: that would be an O(n) in some case,
but if data is like [5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1]
steps would be like 
-> [5, 3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1]
-> [4, 3, 7, 6, -1, 2, 1]
-> [6, 3, 7, -1, -1, 2, 1]
-> [2, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, 1]
-> [3, -1, 7, -1, -1, -1, 1]
-> [7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
-> [1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
-> [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

and we are still on the first element in traversal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see these patterns:

- Once an array value gets a negative value, it will never become positive again:

  - `arr[i] = 0;` and `arr[i] = arr[indexToUpdate];` can only execute when `arr[i]` was strictly positive, and they don't make `arr[i]` negative.
  - `arr[indexToUpdate]--` decreases a value that was already negative
  - `arr[indexToUpdate] = -1` is the only remaining modification of an array element, and it is the only one that changes its sign. And that change is from non-negative to negative
  - There is no case where a negative value is updated to a non-negative value
- One iteration of the loop will *either* increase `i`, *or* turn a non-negative value into a negative value.

  - Increasing `i` can only happen `size` times, as then the loop exits
  - Making a non-negative value negative, can only happen `size` times, as then all values will be negative

Conclusion: the loop can make `2*size` iterations at the most. So this is O(n).

Comment: Certainly I had came up with the same TC as 2N to be appropriate, thanks for this answer